# How to get only IPv4 address(es) for a hostname

Tags: powershell, ip

I am making writing a `Powershell` script that have to automize the initial set-up of a windows machine. For some of the operations I'm gonna need the machine IP but since we are part of a large group (not sure about the terminology) and there's a chance that at some point the same hostname may be associated with 2 or more IP's I want to get all IPv4 IP addresses and based on the result (if there is only 1 on multiple) to write some logic.

Right now I have this:

```
$ips = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("myhostname")
```

but when I execute `$ips.Count` right after I get `2` and when I do the following:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("myhostname") | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString }
```

it turns out that I got the IPv4 and (almost) IPv6 addresses.

If I am sure this will always be the case it's OK, but since I want to check for multiple IPv4 addresses and I don't need the IPv6 at all how can I take only the IPv4 ones and check theirs count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter the result of the `GetHostAddresses()` call by address family. IPv4 addresses have the address family `InterNetwork` while IPv6 addresses have the address family `InterNetworkV6`.

```
$ips = [Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('myhostname') |
       Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } |
       Select-Object -Expand IPAddressToString

@($ips).Count
```